# Equivalent to "pairwise" for a triplet

Tags: single-word-requests, comparisons, science

**Pairwise** may describe the process of comparing entities in pairs. What is the word for the process of describing the comparison of entities in triplet?

[EDIT] Initial research found a single occurrence of triplewise in Statistics: [An example of a stationary, triplewise independent triangular array for which the CLT fails](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2006.09.002). The accepted answer found the same.

Comment: A set of two is a *pair* (among other names), and taking a pair at a time is called *pairwise*. Similarly, a set of three is called a *trio* or *triple*, so analogously, perhaps you could use *triowise* or *triplewise*. The suffix *-wise* is productive. The downside is I imagine these words haven't see much use, if any at all.

Comment: I would describe the comparison of entities in triplet as a ***three-way** comparison*.

Comment: They use *threewise* here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472944/quantifying-pairwise-threewise-etc-overlap-in-a-bipartite-graph

Comment: And they use *n-wise* here (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) suggesting a general pattern.

Comment: Can we reopen this please? I came here looking for a good word to use when writing an answer to this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6476/5 !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most plausible answer would be ***triple-wise*** because in software testing, there are various types of testing, two of which are *pairwise* and *triple-wise* which creates a suite using every **triple** of classes.

Comment: Apparently, I did find a similar use in statistics: [An example of a stationary, triplewise independent triangular array for which the CLT fails](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.spl.2006.09.002)